# How am I supposed to have inherited variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to achieve:

```rb
class Model
    table = "NOT SET"
    self.get(id)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE id = #{id}
    end
end
```

This is my generic model class with an example function.

```rb
class User < Model
    table = "users"
end
```

I want to keep the generic sql functions in the parent class, as they are not required in every single instance. Each class declaration needs the table to be used when running the `get` function.

Regarding instance variables, you don't instance [sic] a class to call `get`. A class variable is shared by the classes in the hierarchy, so that also won't work.

How should I use class variables? How can I do this? In java, I would have a protected variable that each class assigns above the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Raising a hard error on the Model class would be an additional benefit to ensure `table` is implemented on child classes.

Also, by using the `class << self` syntax, you can define private or protected class methods.

```
class Model
  class << self
    def get(id)
      "SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE id = #{id}"
    end

    private

    def table
      raise NotImplementedError
    end
  end
end

class User < Model
  class << self
    private

    def table
      "users"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I never thought of that! Very clever and thank you for the solution.

Comment: So I implemented this and it kind of works, however I now have no idea how to handle a case where a non class method needs access to the table function.

Comment: @Gibbo Each instance can access its own class via `self.class`. Thus, you can call the `table` method of your own class via `self.class.table` from an instance method.

Comment: Perfect thank you my friend, that worked as expected. Hopefully I can learn further from this to help DRY up my code.